# Eigenvectors and EigenValues for $AA^T$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have read that the eigenvalues of A.A' is same as A'.A where ' is the transpose operator. 
How can we obtain the eigenvectors of A.A' if we have the eigenvectors of A'.A ?

Reason:

During eigen value decomposition the matrix A.A' is very big as compared to A'.A which is quite small.

Answer (score 3):

In general you cannot—that the eigenvalues of $AA^T$ and $A^T\!A$ are the same follows from the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Relation_to_eigenvalue_decomposition) of $A$ (see, in particular [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Relation_to_eigenvalue_decomposition)). However, the decomposition also shows that the eigenvalues of $AA^T$ are the left singular vectors of $A$ while those of $A^T\!A$ are the right singular vectors of $A$ which, in general, are unrelated. However, if you're worried about computational complexity you'd probably be better off using svd anyway (or so I've been told...).

---

Update:

Correct me if I've misunderstood the code. If what they claim is that: if $v$ is an eigenvector of $L:=AA^T$ and $\lambda$ is its corresponding eigenvalue, then

$$u:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}A^Tv$$

is an eigenvector of $C:=A^TA$. Then, here is a counter example:

$$A:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow AA^T =A^T\!A=I.$$

So $v_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $v_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ are the eigenvectors of $L$ and $C$ (with corresponding eigenvalue $1$), but

$$u=A^Tv_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1\\ -1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I apologize for giving you this link to ask my question (http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~sis26/Eigencode.htm) but in this link, they calculate the eigenvectors of C(AA') by multiplying A with the eigenvectors of A'A and divide this with the square root of eigenvalues of A'A. According to you, is this incorrect since they basically are trying to do the same thing, reducing time of computation by using A'A and their eigenvectors and eigenvalues?

Comment: @anon, see update to the answer.